# Python/OpenSSL issue: ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found

Tags: python, openssl, homebrew, python-2.x

This error occurred while installing latest Ruby using `ruby-install`.

What I tried:

`brew switch openssl <my_version>`

`brew upgrade openssl`

And many other solutions that were proposed in SO. None solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Though there were a lot of similar questions floating around in SO, I think none of them were able to solve my issue. Thought of adding this question with the fix that solved it for me. I got it from a [medium post](https://medium.com/@megawan/fix-error-root-code-for-hash-md5-was-not-found-b70eac7950ed):

Since Python 2 End of Life Announced as January 1st 2020 as well as brew no longer support python 2. The solution is uninstall the package.

`brew uninstall python@2`

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is actually coming that python2 is not supported, but you can solve it by installing just correct openssl via brew, e.g.

brew install openssl@1.1